# array of allowUnknownTags doesnt work

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3, custom-tags

I have the latest of JsDoc (3.4.3), and as per the documentation of JsDoc, I added array of unknown tags, but got slapped with error of unknow tag

The @foo: tag is not a known tag.
"allowUnknownTags": [ "foo", "usage", "test" ]

Am I missing something ?

Am I expected to write customTag plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

`allowUnknownTags` takes a boolean, not an array.

```
[...]
"tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true,
    "dictionaries": ["jsdoc","closure"]
},
[...]
```

See this question & answer "[create custom tags with jsdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263846/create-custom-tags-with-jsdoc)" for more about defining your own tags in a custom dictionary*.

*: Maybe... I don't really know, but it seems about right.

http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-jsdoc.html

Comment: But jsdoc documenation says http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-jsdoc.html

"The tags.allowUnknownTags property affects how JSDoc handles unrecognized tags. If you set this option to false, and JSDoc finds a tag that it does not recognize (for example, @foo), JSDoc logs a warning. By default, this option is set to true. In JSDoc 3.4.1 and later, you can also set this property to an array of tag names that JSDoc should allow (for example, ["foo","bar"])."